# Why does Google Chrome sometimes auto-disable an extension and require the user to click a Reload link?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

As shown in the image here:

[image: Reload link for borked extension]

Why would Chrome require a user to manually “Reload” an extension? The extension seems to be working for a while, then suddenly a user reports that it has stopped working and I have to instruct him/her to click the “Reload” link.

As an extension developer, I would like to be able to prevent this from happening. Here’s [my extension in the Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kifi/fpjooibalklfinmkiodaamcckfbcjhin).

Screenshot borrowed from [a similar report](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/twZ-ykcH-gI) from another developer.

Comment: I think this can happen when the process hosting the extension crashes. Chrome shows a notification if that happens. Can you reproduce it on your end? If yes, you should enable Chrome logging and try to fish for more information.

Comment: Did you recently update the extension with NEW permissions? If yes, then the extension will automatically be disabled until the user approves the new permissions.

Comment: This is a crashed or killed extensions. Extensions updated with new permissions are generally just disabled.

Comment: @Xan, unable to reproduce it myself. Seems to be pretty rare: only one user has notified me so far out of a few thousand, but others may not have noticed or bothered to report.

Comment: @RobW no recent permissions changes, and from what I’ve read, the UI for authorizing new permissions does not involve a “Reload” link (as abraham suggested).

Comment: I was able to produce the “XYZ extension has crashed” notification and the “Reload” link myself by killing the extension process from the Chrome Task Manager. Thanks for the comment, @Xan. If you post your comment as an answer, I’ll accept it.

I’m sure the user that reported it to me didn’t kill the extension process himself, though. Still curious what would cause it in the wild – and whether my extension code could somehow be at fault.

Comment: You don't always have control over extension-process crashes. It can be the case that the user is running canary or dev channel of Chrome, in which case crash-severity bugs do make it into production, and your user's extension process happens to trigger it. If you run canary channel (which is side-by-side) on all Chrome's supported platforms, you'll be more likely to witness these sorts of issues yourself.

Comment: Looks like Chrome does automatically re-enable a crashed extension when the user restarts Chrome. That’s a relief.